# Google map null on 'LatLngBounds .build()'

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to get google map to automatically limit its view to the added markers.  When using the code below, googleMap becomes Null once the builder.build() line runs.  Can someone tell what's causing this, or perhaps a better way to accomplish the goal?

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

         for (cAddress pp : lstAddr) {                   
              if (googleMap != null) {
                   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                   .position(pp.Coordinates)
                    .title(pp.Street));

                    builder.include(pp.Coordinates);
                }
            }               

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: This code does not change the value of the `googleMap` reference. You're either misreporting the problem, or not showing all relevant code.

Comment: Might have been `null` all the time., since in the loop you are guarding against it and would not notice.

Comment: This code sample is missing some parts. If you execute `LatLngBounds.Builder.build()` with no included points you will get an IllegalStateException, but by the code sample you provided to add a point `googleMap` must not be null. So there is something missing that can be the true cause of the problem.